# How to control execution of parent process after execl() call in C program?

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork, child-process

I have simple C program which executes an application using fork() and execl(). If execl() fails to run the application, then I have to call a function in the parent process and exit from the child process. If execl() successfully runs the application, then I have show a success log from the parent process. So, parent process should wait for the child's execl() call (just the call, not till the end of execution of the application), get some information about it status, and then make decisions and continue its own execution. Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    int iExecRetVal, pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {

    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        iExecRetVal = execl("./flute-static", "./flute-static", "-send", "-a192.168.190.1/6666", "JFlute.1.2.tar.gz", NULL);
        if (iExecRetVal == -1)
        {
            /*execl() failed, need some error handling in the parent process*/
        }
        _exit(0);
    }

    /*Parent's normal execution*/
}

int HandleSuccessFromParent()
{
    /*Should be called when exec call was successful*/
}

int HandleFailureFromParent()
{
    /*Should be called when exec call was NOT successful*/
}
```

We know execl() does not return on success. So, how to call HandleSuccessFromParent() and HandleFailureFromParent() functions properly after the execl() call in the child. Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

The child process needs to exit with an error status (non-zero; 1 is common, `EXIT_FAILURE` is standard C).

The parent process needs to wait for the child to finish, and capture the child's exit status, using [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) or
[`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html).

If you need to know whether the child died but don't want to wait for it to complete, use `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` after a small pause to let the child try and run (a sub-second delay is likely to be long enough).

Comment: IIRC, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) would `_exit(127)` if its `execve` of `/bin/sh` fails so on Linux or Posix I think it is useful to use the 127 exit code in that case (I know no program exiting 127 in other cases)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, and the specification for POSIX [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) includes information about exit status values 126, 127, and 129+ for different error conditions on shells.  You can decide to follow that if you wish.  The crucial point is 'do not exit with status 0 on failure'; exiting with 126, 127, etc is a second-order refinement.

Comment: Indeed it is a refinement, but a quite useful one. GNU `grep` use several (small) exit codes on failure, so using something else than 1 is useful, and using 127 is slightly more useful (since it is a conventional habit in that case).

Comment: Thanks. I am using waitpid() in the parent with WNOHANG. Before it, I am using sleep(1). It works fine when the child process is long enough. But when the child exits normally (without EXIT_FAILURE) within a short duration (probably < 1 sec) it returns -1. How to fix this?

Comment: Use a subsecond sleep — `nanosleep()` or perhaps `usleep()`, or perhaps `select()`, or … To spot whether the child is going to exit, you probably only need to sleep for a few milliseconds; a full second is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution involves `ptrace`. The outline is as follows:

Let the child call `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)`. Let the parent enable `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` option and `waitpid` on the child. In this setup `waitpid` would return upon successful `execl`. Test the status to see if it has a `SIGTRAP` flag set. Let the child continue with `PTRACE_DETACH`.

Comment: True, but probably too high-tech for most of us. I pragmatically prefer [Jonathan Leffler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26617152/841108) in practice.