# Execute background process and check status from parent

Tags: c, background, exec, fork, pid

I'm currently trying to:

1. Execute a background process with a fork() call and execvp() inside the children.
2. If the call to execvp() was successful, adding the PID of the child process to a list.
3. If the call to execvp() returned -1 (error), do not add the PID to the list.

My problem is: if execvp() returns -1 (for instance, if the executable isn't found) I can't "communicate" with the parent proccess since I'm inside the child process in the fork(). And if I use waitpid() to wait for the child, I'm not running a background process (since I lose the concurrency).

I tried using WNOHANG and checking *status with (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 1) but it doesn't work (since the parent process executes "instantly" and doesn't know if the child has exited yet, or that's what I think)

My current code:

```
void background(char *vector[]) {
pid_t childp;
int status;
childp=fork();
    if (childp==-1){ 
        perror("Error using fork \n");
        return;
    }
    if (childp==0) { //Child process
        if (execvp(vector[0],vector)==-1) {
            perror("exec");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
    //Child exited
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 1) {
        //Child exited with error
        return;
    }
}
if (insertProcess(childp,vector)==-1)
    perror("Full list");
else
    updateList();   
}
```

The only solution I've found at the moment is inserting a sleep(1) call before waitpid (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26617152/1339354 ), but this looks more like a hack than something well done. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why not just have the child report success or failure of `exec()` to the parent by some other means, like a file, pipe, or socket?

Comment: I can only repeat my advice from the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using waitpid() with WNOHANG, be sure to especify the child process. If you don't, waitpid() returns status of the last child dead.

I'm not sure if you are trying to save on a list all process that was success. If you are trying it, why not instert always and then delete the process when they die? Control the signal SIGCHLD. In that, use the waitpid for look what process died and delete it in the list. Just deactivate the signal SIGCHLD when you create the process, insert the process on the list and then active again the signal.